# How to make a grid of colours that can be selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, palette

How do I make a kind of grid with colours that can be selected and be saved to a field on selection? Like in the chat options in Twitch.

[image]

Comment: One way (maybe not the greatest out there) would be to generate these as Bitmap images and merely create some PictureBoxes. Like I said, maybe not the best, but it should work.

Comment: It seems like you're asking us to write code for you. Have you tried something?

Comment: @Fuex I'm asking for possible approaches.

Comment: One way is to start learning and using `wpf` (as it has `Popup` and its content concept, as well as styling) over `winforms`. Other: user control with bunch of custom controls (buttons and color radio-buttons) hosted in `ToolStripDropDown`/`ToolStripControlHost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is TableLayoutPanel and panel for each cell of it:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private Color selected_color;
    private List<Color> colors;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        colors = new List<Color>();
        colors.Add(Color.Red);
        colors.Add(Color.Green);
        colors.Add(Color.Blue);
        colors.Add(Color.Yellow);
        colors.Add(Color.Teal);
        colors.Add(Color.RosyBrown);
        colors.Add(Color.Lime);
        colors.Add(Color.Gray);
        tableLayoutPanel.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.OutsetDouble;
        for (byte i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Panel p = tableLayoutPanel.Controls[i] as Panel;
            p.BackColor = colors[i];
            p.Click += panel_click;
        }
    }
    private void panel_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel p = sender as Panel;
        selected_color = p.BackColor;
        lbl_color.Text = selected_color.ToString();
        lbl_color.ForeColor = selected_color;
    }
    private void btn_showMoreColours_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel[] panels = new Panel[4];
        for (byte i = 0; i < panels.Length; i++)
        {
            panels[i] = new Panel();
            panels[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panels[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            panels[i].Name = "panel" + (i + 4);
            panels[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(123, 100);
            panels[i].BackColor = colors[i + 4];
            panels[i].Click += panel_click;
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(panels[i]);
        }
        Size = new Size(Size.Width, Size.Height * 2);
    }
}
```

After clicking a cell you will get Color in field selected_color.
[image: img]

**EDIT:**

A have added show more colours button as well. It will expand like shown below:
[image: img3]

[image: img2]

[Source code here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=59802AFBA7F9048E&id=59802AFBA7F9048E!118)

Answer (score 2):

Windows Form provides the ColorDialog

```
ColorDialog colorDialog = new ColorDialog();
colorDialog.ShowDialog();
```

The selected Color could be called with:

```
colorDialog.Color
```

Comment: But then there is no way to display only a few chosen colours as options.

Comment: Theres a property called CustomColors. Look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393462/how-do-i-specify-what-colors-can-be-picked-in-a-c-sharp-colordialog)